# How big a sample do I need to estimate a percentage?

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power

I have a population of 1000000 data points **without** labels, and I would like to take the **smallest possible** sample from that population for **manual labeling** to estimate with 95 % certainty that the population contains e.g. 2 % unhealthy individuals.

Is there a cool statistical method to do this? It seems like a classical problem, but my googling skills haven't led me in the right direction.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+proportion+sample+size